# split text by words and punctuation marks

Tags: php, regex

I have this text:

> A man’s jacket is of green color. He – the biggest star in modern history – rides bikes very fast (230 km per hour). How is it possible?! What kind of bike is he using? The semi-automatic gear of his bike, which is quite expensive, significantly helps to reach that speed. Some (or maybe many) claim that he is the fastest in the world! “I saw him ride the bike!” Mr. John Deer speaks. “The speed he sets is 133.78 kilometers per hour,” which sounds incredible; sounds deceiving.

I want to have the following resulting array:

```
words[1] = "A"
words[2] = "man's"
words[3] = "jacket"
...
words[n+1] = "color"
words[n+2] = "."
words[n+3] = "He"
words[n+4] = "-"
words[n+5] = "the"
...
```

This array should include all words and punctuation marks separately. Can that be performed using regexp? Can anyone help to compose it?
Thanks!

EDIT: based on request to show my work.
I'm processing the text using the following function, but I want to do the same in regex:

```
$text = explode(' ', $this->rawText);
$marks = Array('.', ',', ' ?', '!', ':', ';', '-', '--', '...');
for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < sizeof($text); $i++, $j++) {
    $skip = false;
    //check if the word contains punctuation mark
    foreach ($marks as $value) {
        $markPosition = strpos($text[$i], $value);
        //if contains separate punctation mark from the word
        if ($markPosition !== FALSE) {
            //check position of punctation mark - if it's 0 then probably it's punctuation mark by itself like for example dash
            if ($markPosition === 0) {
                //add separate mark to array
                $words[$j] = new Word($j, $text[$i], 2, $this->phpMorphy);
            } else {
                $words[$j] = new Word($j, substr($text[$i], 0, strlen($text[$i]) - 1), 0, $this->phpMorphy);
                //add separate mark to array
                $punctMark = substr($text[$i], -1);
                $j += 1;
                $words[$j] = new Word($j, $punctMark, 1, $this->phpMorphy);
            }
            $skip = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$skip) {
        $words[$j] = new Word($j, $text[$i], 0, $this->phpMorphy);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post your attempt at solving the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137575/preg-split-regex-for-splitting-a-sentence-into-words-and-punctuation-marks

Comment: Shoult sentence ending `?!` be separate `?` and `!` or as one `?!` in the result? Should quotes (like `"` or `'`) be included? If `'` should be included, then what about such case as you've posted: `man's` ?

Comment: You should at least try something and then ask it here.

Comment: @AlmaDo, yes, `?` and `!` should be separated. Quotes like this `"` should be included, this quote `'` should be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will split on your specific text.

```
$words = preg_split('/(?<=\s)|(?<=\w)(?=[.,:;!?()-])|(?<=[.,!()?\x{201C}])(?=[^ ])/u', $text);
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/60520)

Comment: Thanks, that's almost correct. But this `(`, `)`, `"` should also be separate array elements, as well as `?!`. Every punctuation mark has to be placed inside it's own array element.

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you very much! The only thing, is that the array contains spaces. For example, for 8th and 29th element. I can probably iterate over the array and remove elements with spaces, however if you could improve your solution is would it great. Also any chance you could eloborate on what exactly the regex you suggested does?

Comment: Amazing, thanks! Can you also please tell me if I needed to add some other punctuation marks to be separated, where in the regex would I put them?

Comment: What do you want to add

Comment: Nothing right now, but I'd like to know how I could this if I needed it :)

Comment: I've thought a little bit and probably would like to add also a `colon` symbol - `:` and `ellipsis` - `...`

Comment: Show me example data.

Comment: For example the sentence `I want the following items: butter, sugar, and flour...`

Comment: Can you please help me? I need to include chr(10) in the regexp too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try making use of **`preg_split`**. Pass your punctuations(*of your choice*) inside the square brackets **`[`** and **`]`**

```
<?php
$str="A man’s jacket is of green color. He – the biggest star in modern history – rides bikes very fast (230 km per hour). How is it possible?! What kind of bike is he using? The semi-automatic gear of his bike, which is quite expensive, significantly helps to reach that speed. Some (or maybe many) claim that he is the fastest in the world! “I saw him ride the bike!” Mr. John Deer speaks. “The speed he sets is 133.78 kilometers per hour,” which sounds incredible; sounds deceiving.";

$keywords=preg_split("/[-,. ]/", $str);

print_r($keywords);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Array (
>       [0] => A
>       [1] => man’s
>       [2] => jacket
>       [3] => is
>       [4] => of
>       [5] => green
>       [6] => color
>       [7] => 
>       [8] => He
>       [9] => –
>       [10] => the
>       [11] => biggest
>       [12] => star
>       [13] => in
>       [14] => modern
>       [15] => history
>       [16] => –

<sup>Message truncated to prevent abuse of resources ... Shankar ;)</sup>

Comment: It seems that the dot should be in the output array, so splitting by it wouldn't make sense. Also don't feed the helpvampires